# Descenders occasionally clipped in feed items

Tags: bug, ios-app

In certain circumstances descenders are clipped in feed items:

[image: clipped descenders]

The first instance in the screenshot is only barely noticeable, but it gets progressively worse in the subsequent examples. The text is even clipped above the baseline in the highlighted "Comment" portion on the right. This doesn't always seem to happen, but I can't really tell what the trigger is.